# list(x), where x is a generator object, doesn't behave as a list of all next(x) results?

Tags: python, list, generator

I have:

```
def f():
    founded = list()
    for i in range(10):
        founded.append({i: i})
        yield founded
```

It's simplification of generator I wrote such that it remembers the previous results for every `next` call hence having the list and yielding it (is there a better way?).

Now, the `next` behavior is expected:

```
>>> a = f()
>>> next(a)
[{0: 0}]
>>> next(a)
[{0: 0}, {1: 1}]
```

However:

```
>>> b = f()
>>> list(b)
[[{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0
: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}
, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1
: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}
, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}], [{0: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {8: 8}, {9: 9}]]
```

Why it behaves like above, instead of returning `[{0,0}, {1: 1}, ..., {9:9}]` or even `[[{0:0}], [{0:0}, {1: 1}], ...` ?

Comment: I don't have this issue in python 3.10.2 and the behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you `yield`, you send *the same list object out*. It's not separate list objects, it is one and the same object:

```
>>> a = f()
>>> first_result = next(a)
>>> second_result = next(a)
>>> first_result
[{0: 0}, {1: 1}]
>>> second_result
[{0: 0}, {1: 1}]
>>> first_result is second_result
True
```

`first_result` and `second_result` reference the same list object, they are not independent. You simply didn't take a new look at the previous results every time you called `next()`.

If you want these lists to be separate independent objects, you need to yield copies instead:

```
def f():
    founded = []
    for i in range(10):
        founded.append({i: i})
        yield founded[:]  # create a copy to yield
```

Note that if the *consumer* needs to keep track of previous values too, then it should be *their responsibility* to keep a cache, not your generator itself. In other words, I'd not do this at all.

Comment: I'll accept you're answer in "9 minutes"! Thanks though. :)